# jQuery: restricting the datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i couldn't figure out on how to do this (using minDate): by default i want my datepicker only allowing to pick dates >= today.

how would this work?

thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `minDate:0` option in the call to datepicker.

This will only allow you to select a date in the next 30 days:

```
jQuery("#date_field").datepicker({
  minDate: 0,
  maxDate: 30
});
```

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation on the [minDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-minDate) option

Answer (score 0):

I got this from [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate)..

Try

```
$('.selector').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date());
```